Laravel 11: How to pass a data from multiple function/method inside a controller?
I do have this set up in my Controller, which has three functions namely, func1, func2, and lastly
func3.
The current error that I am currently facing throws this error message:
Internal Server Error

Too few arguments to function
0 passed and exactly 1 expected

I do not know if I am doing the passing of the variable improperly. However, I will provide the snippets of the code that I am currently working on.
Now, considering func1 is where the condition statement is going so it goes like this;
public function func1()
    {
        $counter = UserSizes::where('user_uid', 'johnd01')->count();
        if ($counter > 0) {
           //display the selected sizes by the user
            $this->func2($counter);
        } else {
           //since it is zero the user did not have selected any sizes.
            $this->func3($counter);
        }
        
    }

as you can see, if the counter has greater than 0, it will fall into the func2, and I want the counter data to be passed on to the func2, like I want my func2 to access that data as well.
so as per my func2.
public function func2($counter)
    {
        $getSizes= UserSizes::where('user_uid', 'johnd01')->get();
        return view('auth.user_pref', [
            'getSizes' => $getSizes,
            'counter' => $counter,
        ]);
    }

The main thing that I want to achieve is that in the main function, I want to filter it to the users who does not have the sizes and who does have selected sizes,
and in the blade file.
so it goes like this in the blade file:
@if ($counter <0)
// display the selection of sizes
@else
// display the selected sizes of the user.          
@endif

I'll just use the if statement to change the UI for users who have selected size wherein I will display their selected sizes and otherwise to the users who did not have selected sizes to display the selection for them to select their desired sizes.
I appreciate any help or ideas!

In your blade template, adjust the condition to correctly check the counter value:
@if ($counter > 0)
<!-- Display the selected sizes of the user -->
<h1>Selected Sizes</h1>
<ul>
    @foreach ($getSizes as $size)
        <li>{{ $size->size }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@else
<!-- Display the selection for the user to choose sizes -->
<h1>Select Your Sizes</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('saveUserSizes') }}">
    @csrf
    <!-- Example of input fields for sizes -->
    <label for="size1">Size 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="size1" name="sizes[]">
    
    <label for="size2">Size 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="size2" name="sizes[]">
    
    <button type="submit">Save Sizes</button>
</form>
@endif


It is indeed working and thank you as well for emphasizing the route for saveusersize.
